# Failing to create and share a Torrent (with both DHT and trackers)

Tags: networking, bittorrent

Just trying to seed and download [my newly created](https://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Torrent) Torrent.

I'm creating a Torrent with qBitTorrent, with/without DHT, and with/without [trackers](http://www.torrenttrackerlist.com/torrent-tracker-list/) (tried all 4 combinations). I'm of course checking "start seed immediately". I then send this Torrent file to a remote PC or to another PC on my LAN, and none of them manage to download it. It just says "Stalled" on the client.

The only time I managed to download was when I simultaneously open [another client](https://www.freedownloadmanager.org/) on the same PC, and loaded the Torrent file there. But now even that somewhy doesn't work anymore (maybe it's because I'm now connected my phone's hotspot instead of my company's WiFi? I don't know, seems weird).

All of these clients were able to download normal Torrents from the Internet just fine.

I wonder if this problem occurs because of the NAT? I can't manually forward the relevant ports to check.

I thought this would be plug-and-play to be fair.

Using Windows 10.

Thanks so much!